# How to mock DB for unit tests

Tags: mysql, unit-testing, go, mocking, go-gorm

I have UserRepo like this:

```
type users struct {
   *gorm.DB
}

func NewMySqlUsersRepository(db *gorm.DB) repository.IUsers {
    return &users{
        DB: db,
    }
}
```

Corresponding methods implementation

```
func (r *users) Save(user *domain.User) (*domain.User, *errors.RestErr) {
  err := r.DB.Model(&domain.User{}).Create(&user).Error

  if err != nil {
    logger.Error("error occurred when create user", err)
    return nil, errors.NewInternalServerError(errors.ErrSomethingWentWrong)
  }

  return user, nil
}
```

For database mock, I am using sqlmock. But how do I mock this method for unit tests? And in Gorm how to mock for other databases queries?

Answer (score 1):

Mocking in Go Is all about Go Interfaces. You will have to create an interface for the repository and implement the Interface methods.

```
type interface IUserRepository{
     save(user *UserModel) (*userModel, Err)
}
```

Now all you need to do is to create a mock struct along with the user struct. Both of these structs will implement IUserRepository. You might also want to use Popular mocking/testing frameworks like [go-mock](https://github.com/golang/mock) or [testify](https://github.com/stretchr/testify) for creating mocks.

Now, you will have to implement a factory method such that it will return mockStruct depending on the condition. You can inject the condition variable with context, env variable, or any other way.

```
func NewMySqlUsersRepositoryFactory(ctx context.Context, env string, db *gorm.DB) repository.IUsers {
    if env == "test" {
        // This is a mocked struct ...
        return mock.MockUsers{}
    }
     // This is a actual struct... 
    return &users{
        DB: db,
    }
}
```

Comment: I have written a blog on the same line. You might want to check this out. [link](https://ss-shailesh28.medium.com/mocking-external-dependencies-in-go-e57e19b0e59c)